# kernelized l1 norm and the representer theorem

Tags: logistic, regularization, kernel-trick

I'm trying to derive a kernel-ized $l_1$ penalty for logistic regression. I have been looking at the slides [Learning with Sparsity Inducing Norms](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/mlss08_fbach.pdf) along with the slides on [Regularization and Variable
Selection via the Elastic Net](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/enet_talk.pdf).

On page 20 of reference [2](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/enet_talk.pdf) they add a $l_1$ penalty of the form
$\lambda_1\sum_{i=1}^n|\alpha_i|$ with little explanation. Given we want a $l_1$ norm of the form $\sum_{i=1}^D|w_i|$, I think we can use the representer theorem to help things along.

On page 36 of [1](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/mlss08_fbach.pdf), "Regularization and representer theorem", they say that for the $l_2$ norm the minimized function w.r.t weights $w$ is of the form 
$w = \sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\Phi(x_j)$ and then say that this is also equal to $\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_jk(.,x_j)$. I tried looking at the reference for this equality but found it totally incomprehensible.

As best as I can figure, the $l_1$ norm should be something like

$||\tilde{w}||_1 = \sum_i|\tilde{w}_i| \le |\sum_i\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_j\Phi(x_j)|^{(i)}$

$|\sum_i\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_j\Phi(x_j)|^{(i)} = |\sum_i\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_jk(.,x_j)|^{(i)} = |\alpha^TK1|$

where $1$ is the column vector of ones.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why is $f = \sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\Phi(x_j) =
       \sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_jk(.,x_j)$?
2. What should the $l_1$ norm look like?